# GraphQL Code Generator: Decorate URL with query string

Tags: rtk-query, graphql-codegen

I am using `graphql-codegen` yarn package to generate React hooks
`graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml`

I want to decorate every GraphQL endpoint call with an operation name, so I could see the operation name in the DevTools console:
[image: DevTools Network tab]

I have tried to find a Code Generator plugin for this purpose but with no luck.
How can I achieve my desired goal?

config codegen.yml:

```
schema: 'https://localhost:5001/api/graphql/'

overwrite: true
documents: './src/**/*.graphql'
generates:
  ./src/graphql/schema.graphql:
    plugins:
      - schema-ast
  ./src/graphql/graphqlTypes.ts:
    - typescript
  ./src/graphql/:
    preset: near-operation-file
    presetConfig:
      extension: .ts
      folder: ../hooks
      baseTypesPath: graphqlTypes.ts
    plugins:
      - typescript-operations
      - typescript-rtk-query:
          importBaseApiFrom: 'graphql/baseApi'
          exportHooks: true
```

My `baseApi.ts` looks like this:

```
import { createApi, retry } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { graphqlRequestBaseQuery } from '@rtk-query/graphql-request-base-query';
import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
import { GraphQLClient } from 'graphql-request';

const client = new GraphQLClient(
  `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/graphql`
);
const cookies = new Cookies();
const token = cookies.get('.AspNetCore.Application.Id');
client.setHeader('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
client.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
client.setHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

export default client;

const staggeredBaseQuery = retry(graphqlRequestBaseQuery({ client }), {
  maxRetries: 2,
});

export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: staggeredBaseQuery,
  endpoints: () => ({}),
  keepUnusedDataFor: 5,
  refetchOnMountOrArgChange: false,
});
```

My generated hook looks like this:

```
import * as Types from '../graphqlTypes';

import { api } from 'graphql/baseApi';
export type SetPreferenceMutationVariables = Types.Exact<{
  name: Types.Scalars['String'];
  value: Types.Scalars['String'];
}>;

export type SetPreferenceMutation = {
  __typename?: 'Mutation';
  setPreference?: boolean | null | undefined;
};

export const SetPreferenceDocument = `
    mutation setPreference($name: String!, $value: String!) {
  setPreference(name: $name, value: $value)
}
    `;

const injectedRtkApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    setPreference: build.mutation<
      SetPreferenceMutation,
      SetPreferenceMutationVariables
    >({
      query: (variables) => ({ document: SetPreferenceDocument, variables }),
    }),
  }),
});

export { injectedRtkApi as api };
export const { useSetPreferenceMutation } = injectedRtkApi;
```

I found this piece of code: [graphql-code-generator/packages/plugins/typescript/rtk-query/src/visitor.ts](https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/blob/e5b76273356acb93ed5497575a6e45b8ca494afa/packages/plugins/typescript/rtk-query/src/visitor.ts#L96)  but I could not find the option to update the URL.
Looks like I need to write my own plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below info will help.

If you want to be able to use multiple endpoints, you can create your link like:

```
const link = new RestLink({ endpoints: { v1: 'api.com/v1', v2: 'api.com/v2' } });
```

Extra code has to be provided to each query:

```
const postTitleQuery1 = gql`
  query PostTitle {
    post @rest(type: "Post", path: "/post", endpoint: "v1") {
      id
      title
    }
  }
`;
const postTitleQuery2 = gql`
  query PostTitle {
    post @rest(type: "[Tag]", path: "/tags", endpoint: "v2") {
      id
      tags
    }
  }
`;
```

Source: [official docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-rest/).